# Failing to apply negative lookahead to select column using regex

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, regex, python-re

I have the below Pandas dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
dat1 = pd.DataFrame({'col1' : ['A', 'B', 'A', 'C'], 'col2_y' : ['Z', 'Z', 'X', 'Y']})
dat1.filter(regex = "(?!_y)")
```

I want to select the columns which do NOT contain `"_y"`. However the above code is returning the whole dataframe.

Could you please help to point out what went wrong with the above code?

Comment: Non regex: `dat1[dat1.columns[~dat1.columns.str.contains('_y')]]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this solve your issue?

```
dat1.filter(regex="^(?!.*_y)")
```

Your negative lookahead assertion `?!` should be inside the parentheses, along with `.*` to ensure we exclude columns containing "_y" anywhere in their names.